# Django Partition Filter Snippet

Tags: python, django, code-snippets

I'm using one of the partition Django snippets to split data into 3 columns and while everything is working, I don't know how to call the middle partition.

**Snippet**:

```
@register.filter
def partition(thelist, n):
try:
    n = int(n)
    thelist = list(thelist)
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    return [thelist]
p = len(thelist) / n
return [thelist[p*i:p*(i+1)] for i in range(n - 1)] + [thelist[p*(i+1):]]
```

**Template**:

```
{% for x in y|partition:"3"|first %} (working, shows first 1/3)
{% for x in y|partition:"3"|middle %} (not working)
{% for x in y|partition:"3"|last %} (working, shows last 1/3)
```

Obvously the "middle" is incorrect. I tried "second" and it didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`first` and `last` are template filters to get the first and last elements of a list. There is not template filter to get the second, third etc. elements. You have to use a `for item in ..` construct:

```
{% for row in mylist|partition:"3" %}
    {% for item in row %}
        do something with {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. While your code is working, it is not exactly what I was looking for as my goal was to split the data into thirds and the above is showing all data 3x. Any suggestions how to slice the data into even thirds?